# General American: very as / ˈvɛɹi / or / ˈveɹi /, more as / ˈmɔɹ / or / ˈmoɹ /, and chair as / t͡ʃɛəɹ / or / t͡ʃeəɹ /

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, ipa, rhoticity

I read this [comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxGWdoau7vc&lc=UgxwPEWf4Nde_X7qawx4AaABAg.9E6QoYsGT629EAqNDoIesg) on Youtube.

> is it possible that the sound / ɹ / tends to close the vowels that
> precede it? For example, at least to me, [very] / ˈvɛɹi / sounds more
> like / ˈveɹi /, [more] / ˈmɔɹ / more like / ˈmoɹ /, [chair] / t͡ʃɛəɹ /
> more like / t͡ʃeəɹ /, etc. Is it at least partially correct?

The maker of the video answered:

> I think the R does close the vowel in some cases, yes! In particular
> with words like 'more'. The other examples there may be a closed a
> bit, but I think it is also possible and common for the vowel to stay
> more 'open'.

Like in the comment I hear [very]  as / ˈveɹi /, [more]  as ˈmoɹ /, [chair] as / t͡ʃeəɹ /. So which pronunciations are the most common in General American?

Comment: The ones with the close vowel before R are the most prevalent. I am certain we have duplicates on this, but [they're hard to find](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=tense+lax+neutralized). Remember that the American R tends to be retroflex, which may have some effect on all this.

Comment: We don't use either / t͡ʃɛəɹ / or / t͡ʃeəɹ / in General American. It's either / t͡ʃɛɹ / or / t͡ʃeɹ /. And those are allophones so it doesn't matter which one you use — most Americans won't even notice the difference.

Comment: @PeterShor Yeah I was having trouble mouthing out [t͡ʃɛə̯ɻ] or [t͡ʃeə̯ɻ] or whatever it might be; one might even make the argument that it’s [t͡ʃɛ˞] or [t͡ʃe˞], but all those transcriptions risk blurring the phonemic perception that *chair* comprises a sequence of just 3 phonemes in a row, no matter how that works out in actual pronunciation. The first we think of not as a consonant cluster but as a single integral phoneme, while the rime’s vowel and the rhotic in the coda are each [single archiphonemes ⫽E⫽ and ⫽R⫽](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme#Neutralization_and_archiphonemes).